# Why should this nix-env command without -b download pre-built packages?

Tags: nix

https://nixos.org/manual/nix/unstable/quick-start.html says:

> Install some packages from the channel:
>
> ```
>  nix-env --install --attr nixpkgs.hello
> ```
>
> This should download pre-built packages; it should not build them
> locally (if it does, something went wrong).

Why "This should download pre-built packages"?

Does that require `-b`, which is absent in the example?

If the default case (without -b) implies downloading prebuilt packages, then why do we need option -b for explicitly specifying downloading prebuilt packages in the first place?

Comment: Insofar as you're asking about Nix-the-package-manager more than Nix-the-programming-language (used to describe derivations that Nix-the-package-manager can install), I might argue that this is probably better suited to [unix.se].

Answer (score 2):

It should download prebuilt packages by default without needing extra options because the developers who operate cache.nixos.org build most or all of the packages defined by the official NixOS channels, and they store the results there.  The system doing these builds is called Hydra.  Your Nix software is configured to use cache.nixos.org as a "substituter", so it checks there to see if things are cached before it builds them.  You can add your own substituters as well.

Comment: Thanks. If the default case (without -b) implies downloading prebuilt packages, then why do we need option -b for explicitly specifying downloading prebuilt packages in the first place?

Comment: The default is to either download prebuilt packages or to build packages ourselves depending on the situation at the cache for each thing we need.  If you build some Nix expression that you defined yourself, then some things might be downloaded from the cache but other things specific to your Nix expression would be built on your machine.

Comment: What is the difference between -b and the default case?

Comment: You can run `man nix-env` to see the documentation of that option, which explains it clearly.  It is short for `--prebuilt-only` and it means:  "Use only derivations for which a substitute is registered, i.e., there is a pre-built binary available that can be downloaded. Thus, no packages will be built from source."

Comment: Given a package to install with `nix-env -i -b`, is the package necessary to have a substitute registered? If not, does `-b` make the installation fail?